# How to manage session on a load balancing architecture?

Tags: session, architecture, load-balancing

I Was facing a problem in my load balancing architecture. Please suggest something on How to manage session on a load balancing architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP you have something called as [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

IN this method you can define your customized function for session handling e.g. you can handle sessions with database.

Also load balancers provide concept of [sticky-sessions](http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2007/08/load-balancer-persistence-sticky.html) in which sessiosn are save on load balancers itself

Comment: Solution for DB seems inappropriate it will increase load on DB will go with Stiky Sessions thing, could you elaborate sticky session?

Comment: Dear Friend, That blog is having all the details. Still, are you using Akamai ?

Comment: We have implemented the Elastic Load Balancer architecture using Akamai. In that case Akamai gives us a control panel through which we can set sticky sessions on or off. I am not sure how will you implement sticky sessions using your own Load Balancer.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions Jatin. Will research on it and go ahead.

Comment: You are welcome oM. Please dont forget to aaccept the answer if it was useful for you :-)